# ionic: parent cannot update child input value during ionViewWillEnter

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Framework level**
Parent page with child page.
Child page takes `@Input` data from parent page.
After push and pop, parent page set variable in `ionViewWillEnter`.
However, the value is not updated in child page.

**Playground**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bebbdi
Please look at about tab

**Structure:**
Parent page controls variable `firstAttempt` when to reset using `ionViewWillEnter`.
Parent set `firstAttempt` to true
The **target** is to reset `firstAttempt` whenever enter parent page.
Child page takes parent data using `@Input`.
Child page pushes next page if not `firstAttempt`.

Hope it won't be to messy to read.
Thank you for all input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the solution for the problem.

In your `About.ts` file, initialize the variable as `firstAttempt: boolean = true;`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-about',
  templateUrl: 'about.html'
})
export class AboutPage {
  firstAttempt: boolean = true;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {  }
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    console.log('about page ionViewWillEnter');
    this.firstAttempt = true;
  }
}
```

### Edited

in your `child.ts` file

```
next() {
    alert(this.firstAttempt)
    if (this.firstAttempt) {
      console.log("first attempt");
      this.firstAttempt = false;
    } else {
      console.log(">= second attempt");
      this.navCtrl.push(NextPage);
      this.firstAttempt = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: appreciate your reply. However, it cannot solve the problem. Please check the case that about > next > about. After pop back to about page, firstAttempt is meant to be set to true / reset. Also, you can check console log; when first attempt, there's log: first attempt; when not first attempt, log: >= second attempt and direct to next page

Comment: This will reset the variable firstAttempt to true each time when you enter the about page

Comment: That's a different tactic, thanks. But do you know why I can't set it every time entering parent page(about) and pass to child through @Input?